# Git/Bash slow when run from Windows on shared Linux folder

Tags: git, mingw, msysgit

1. My Ubuntu box shares my codebase in `\\ubuntubox\codebase` full read / write permissions (samba).
2. On my Windows 7 64-bit box, I've mapped the above shared folder to X:. I can access / write / execute / delete files at whim.
3. Running a simple `git status` from a terminal in Linux: 1 to 3 seconds to get the status
4. Running a `git status` from the MINGW terminal in the Windows box (what is installed by default by Git for windows) on the shared folder: **10-15 seconds**.

Is there perhaps a "trick" I'm missing to make git.exe (the Windows executable) work faster on a shared folder?

At the moment I'm using putty to ssh into the ubuntu box and do all git stuff from the command line. However, my IDE of choice (the awesome PHPStorm) has a tremendously helpful git integration which I'd like to continue to use, wihtout having to wait 10 secs+ for each git command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no trick about working on a git repository located on a network share, because git isn't designed to work like this.

It is designed instead to work locally, and communicate changes with remote locations. To do so you need to:

- Make sure you're connected to `\\ubuntubox\codebase`
- run `git clone //ubuntubox/codebase` (notice, no backslashes) from a local folder

Then you'll have a local copy of the repository, and you'll be able to push/pull your changes back with the remote place (`origin` repository).

Comment: I had a feeling I would resort to this... :) Working locally is indeed magnificently fast. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can also consider upvoting the answers you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NFS instead of Samba to share your files.

I have never tried it with git like that but in other cases I have seen a great performance improvement when switching from Samba to NFS.